# Peewee - How to Batch Update and How to Only Update Rows which have been Edited?

Tags: python, bottle, peewee, batch-updates

I'm trying to learn Peewee and Bottle by making a note taking app for books.

The models and relationships consist of `Subject -< Book -< Chapter -< Note`.

On the `note.tpl` page, I wish to display all notes in a table and allow the end-user to update any note as he pleases:

```
<FORM action="/notes" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="{{chapter.id}}"
    <% note_ids = ""
       for note in chapter.notes:
           note_ids += note.id
       end
       note_ids = note_ids[:-1]
    %>
    <input type="hidden" name="note_ids" value="{{note_ids}}" />
    <TABLE>
        <TR><TD>Note Meta</TD><TD>Note</TD></TR>
        % for note in chapter.notes:
            <TR><TD>
                Tag:<input type="text" value="note_tag#{{note.id}}" /><br />
                Pg#:<input type="text" value="page_number#{{note.id}}" /><br />
                </TD>
                <TD> <textarea name="note#{{note.id}}" /><br />
            </TR>
        % end
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Lets say I have a controller like this:

```
@app.route('/notes/, method='POST')
def note_action():
    for i in request.forms.get('note_ids').split(','):
        note = Note(tag=request.forms.get('note_tag#' + i),
        page_number=request.forms.get('page_number#' + i),
        chapter=request.forms.get('chapter_id'))
        note.save()
    chapter = Chapter.select().where(Chapter.id==chapter_id)
    return template('notes', chapter=chapter)
```

This is bad for three reasons:

1) It doesn't do a batch update but updates each note one at a time. How would I do a batch update in Peewee?

2) It updates every single note, even notes that have not been edited by the user. How would I be able to determine which rows have been edited and update only those rows?

Short of using JQuery (or using it to a very limited degree), how should I go about solving these?

Answer (score 1):

Re your first question, better late than never perhaps: Peewee API doesn't have an addBatch() method like in JDBC's java.sql.Statement.  Instead you begin a transaction via "with" and do much work, with Python handling the commit of the transaction.  This post from the Peewee author illustrates that approach (unfortunately the link at the end of that post about bulk loading data is broken):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/peewee-orm/YWamQxAYxWU/HTu_wUNLHKUJ

Comment: Peewee has [bulk insert](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#bulk-inserts) capabilities, and to perform bulk updates you can create an `UPDATE` query. If you want to batch a number of updates or inserts, then just wrap them in a transaction using the `with db.atomic()` context manager.

Comment: @coleifer: is there any meaningful difference between sql-style addBatch() and the Python/Peewee approach of "with db.atomic()"?  I don't want to spread false information.

Comment: I'm not sure what sql-style "addBatch()" is, so I can't really say.